# Unity3d return to original rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a 3D object to slowly return to its original rotation when the player lets go of any of the influencing keys.

This is what I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShipController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float turnRate;
    public Transform baseOrientation;

    private Vector3 worldAxis, worldAxisRelative;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        worldAxis = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        worldAxisRelative = transform.TransformDirection (worldAxis);
    }

    void Update () {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            rb.transform.Rotate (Vector3.down * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
            rb.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            rb.transform.Rotate (Vector3.left * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
            rb.transform.Rotate (Vector3.right * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        axisAlignRot = Quaternion.FromToRotation (worldAxisRelative, worldAxis) ;
        rb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rb.transform.rotation, axisAlignRot * transform.rotation, 1.0f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

But I am having no luck with it. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this should be relativly easy done by just saving the original rotation and using `Quaternion.RotateTowards`. You don't need to use the rigidbody for this at all.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShipController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Quaternion originalRotation;

    void Start () {
        originalRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.down * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.left * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.right * turnRate * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, originalRotation, 1.0f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This should work. You might have to change the conditions a bit because currently you are also turning towards the original rotation if you are actually pressing any of the four keys.